# How to post JSON data using lynx command line?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, gnu, lynx

I am able to post JSON using curl like below and able to get JSON output

> curl -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -d '{"xyz":"abc"} http://mymachine.com/test.jsp

output -

> {"sucess":"pqr"}

But in my stage box I dont have curl so trying to do same using lynx

I tried below

> echo -e '{"xyz":"abc"}\n---\n' |  lynx -head 'Content-Type: application/json' -post_data http://mymachine.com/test.jsp

above command is not working, I am getting output {"error":"pqr"} which will come only when test service didnt receive any output.

Can please let me know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Lynx is primarily an interactive browser. Why do you want to use it to invoke a web service? Why can't you stick with curl or wget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [lynx man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx), you'll see that `-head` is for sending `HEAD` requests, it doesn't set a http header for the request.

There is no option listed in the man page that would set a request header, the content type for `POST` requests will always be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You'll probably have to find another tool to do the job, try to look if something useful is installed (`wget`, `nc`, `ncat`, `bash`, ...).

If you tell me what's available, I can probably give you a concrete example.